# Add ClientGroupHeaderTemplate without showing column angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to create a small grid for "users" which is grouped by "created_dateTime".
Now the plan is to change the ClientGroupHeaderTemplate, to add a checkbox to check all sub elements, for the group without showing it "created_dateTime" as a column in the grid.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [group]="groups">
            <kendo-grid-column field="created_dateTime"> // *I don;t want to show this column but I want to alter the kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate*
                <ng-template kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate let-group let-field="field" let-value="value">
                   <input type="checkbox" (change)="checkAll($event)" [(ngModel)]="checkAllEDNE"/>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>

 <kendo-grid-column
        field="ProductID"
        title="ID"
        [width]="80"
      ></kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name"></kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
```

component.

````
public groups = [{ field: "created_dateTime" }];

    public gridData = process([{
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "created_dateTime": "20-10-2022",
        "Discontinued": false
      }, {
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "created_dateTime":  "22-10-2022",
        "Discontinued": true
      }
    ], {
     group: this.groups
    });
    ```
````

Comment: You should definitely include some code and specify where exactly you are struggling. Otherwise you will not get benefitial feedback.

Comment: hi @FabianStrathaus code added